# Can't boot from usb drive on LG Gram running Windows 10 Pro

Tags: boot, usb

Followed the tutorial to create a bootable usb drive from ubuntu 18.04 iso - it doesn't boot.
Tried several other ways/utilities, still getting:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\NULL - Not Found
Failed to load image \EFI\BOOT\NULL: Not Found
start_image() returned Not Found
```

Answer (score 2):

Obtained from [this Korean blog](https://blog.1day1.org/596):

Inside the USB drive go to `\EFI\BOOT\`, copy `grubx64.efi` and rename the copy to `NULL` (not `NULL.efi` but simply `NULL`)

It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, will try next time; for now, I've set it up on my MacBook through Parallels

Comment: Tried it on LG gram 14 inch 2018 edition. It worked!